# Makefile with subdirectories does not find headers

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, cross-compiling

I have the following directory structure (on Ubuntu):

```
MyProject/
    Here is my Makefile
MyProject/src/headers
    Here are more subfolders and .hpp files
MyProject/src/sources
    Here are two .cpp files (main.cpp and another.cpp)
```

So I have used [this](http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/articles/make/#multiple-source-directories) tutorial to write my makefile, that looks like this:

```
cppsrc = $(wildcard src/sources/*.cpp)
obj = $(cppsrc:.cpp=.o) 
flags = -I/usr/include/boost_1_72_0/ -pthread 

cross: $(obj)   
      i686-atom-linux-gnu-g++ -o $@ $^ $(flags)
```

It detects the .cpp file in the subdirectory (yay!).
But it does not detect the header files included in the .cpp file. So I have included the header in another.cpp like this:

```
#include "src/headers/another.hpp"
```

The command make cross gives me this error message:

```
g++    -c -o src/sources/another.o src/sources/another.cpp
src/sources/another.cpp:6:10: fatal error: src/headers/another.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "src/headers/another.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'src/sources/another.o' failed
make: *** [src/sources/another.o] Error 1
```

The error message makes me believe that makeapp looks for the header file in a position like this:

```
MyProject/src/sources/src/headers/
```

Is my assumption correct? What can I do to solve this?
Hope that someone will be able to help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: That has nothing to do with make.  It's not make that's showing this error, it's the compiler... if you ran that compiler invocation yourself at your shell prompt, without make, you'd get the same error.  You need to ask how the compiler searches for header files.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! So I will go and check the compiler documentation then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell your compiler to look in the local directory (`-I.`), but there is a more serious problem: you are compiling your files with the HOST compiler and linking them together with a CROSS compiler. This will result in errors.

To fix it, you need to set variables used in the default `COMPILE.cc` rule, defined as follows:

```
COMPILE.cpp = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
%.o: %.cpp
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

So in your case:

```
CXX = i686-atom-linux-gnu-g++
CXXFLAGS += -I. -I/usr/include/boost_1_72_0/
LDFLAGS += -lpthread

cppsrc = $(wildcard src/sources/*.cpp)
obj = $(cppsrc:.cpp=.o) 

cross: $(obj)
      $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped a lot!